# .NET Core CSV deserialiser

Tags: library, c#, .net, csv

I read [this](https://github.com/indy-singh/StringsAreEvil/pull/1#issue-193570743) some time ago, and I assumed that by now all C# based CSV parsers would be using pipes and spans.

CSVHelper and TinyCSV don't appear to use spans/pipes, so I was wondering if any other library does?  I have been unable to find a library that is maintained and takes advantage of these technologies in .NET Core.

Thanks!